# In-App Purchase with an IBAction / Button

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm using Ray Wenderlich tutorial to create IAP (http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/) , everything works well, but I don't want to use table view on my app, I want to use just a simple IBAction button to make the purchase.

So basically this is the way it works on the table view. First identify the products:

```
 + (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
     static dispatch_once_t once;
     static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
     dispatch_once(&once, ^{
         NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                       @"com.companyname.10coins",
                                       @"com.companyname.20coins",
                                       nil];
         sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
     });
     return sharedInstance;
 }
```

Then trigger the action:

```
 - (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

        UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

        NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
        [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product]; }


     - (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

         NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

         SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
         [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
     }
```

So I'm trying to make a simple button to trigger the action, like this:

```
 - (IBAction)button10Coins:(id)sender {

     SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:@"com.companyname.10coins"];
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
 }
```

But I get a warning "Incompatible Pointer types".

After the it starts the code works great and I'm able to finalize the purchase, the only problem is creating the IBAction properly. Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that helped me here! I finally made it work.

I came out with a different code. I will try to explain everything I did here so if anyone wants to do the same.

Fist create an App ID on iOS Provisioning Portal and create the IAP Purchase on iTunes Connect.

Then, get this project: http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/implementing-inapp-purchase-in-xcode.html and import the "SFHFKeychainUtils.h" and .m files. Don't forget to add the SFHFKeychainUtils.m to your Compile Sources (Project -> Build Phases - > Compile Sources).

Now the code:

.h

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

(...)

<SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIButton *feature2Btn;
IBOutlet UILabel *featureLabel, *statusLabel;
UIAlertView *askToPurchase;

int64_t coins;
IBOutlet UILabel * coinsLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIButton *feature2Btn;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UILabel *featureLabel, *statusLabel;
@property (nonatomic, assign)  int64_t coins;

-(IBAction)button10Coins:(id)sender;
-(BOOL)IAPItemPurchased;
```

.m

```
#import "SFHFKeychainUtils.h"

@synthesize feature2Btn, featureLabel, statusLabel, coins;
#define kStoredData @"com.IAPID.10coins"
```

The button:

```
-(IBAction)button10Coins:(id)sender {

    askToPurchase = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle:@"IAP"
                     message:@"Would you like to buy 10 coins?"
                     delegate:self
                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                     otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", @"No", nil];
    askToPurchase.delegate = self;
    [askToPurchase show];
}
```

Check if IAP is available:

```
#pragma mark AlertView Delegate

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (alertView==askToPurchase) {
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        // user tapped YES, but we need to check if IAP is enabled or not.
        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {

            NSLog(@"IAP: Checking if IAP Available");

            SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.IAPID.10coins"]];

            request.delegate = self;
            [request start];


        } else {
            UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Prohibited"
                                message:@"Parental Control is enabled, cannot make a purchase!"
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [tmp show];
        }
    }
} }
```

Request the product, if available, or cancel the purchase if not:

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

NSLog(@"IAP: Received Response");

// remove wait view here
statusLabel.text = @"";

SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];

if (count>0) {

    NSLog(@"IAP: Available, starting transaction");

    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];


    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.IAPID.10coins"];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];


} else {

    NSLog(@"IAP: Item not found");

    UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Internet Connection Required"
                        message:@"You must connect to a Wi-Fi  or cellular data network to perform an In-App Purchase."
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [tmp show];
} }
```

Finally, the action:

```
#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: {

            // show wait view here
            NSLog(@"IAP: Processing...");}
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:{

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view and unlock feature 2
            statusLabel.text = @"Done!";
            UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Completet"
                                message:@"The purchase has been completed!"
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

            [tmp show];


            NSError *error = nil;
            [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:@"IAPNoob01" andPassword:@"whatever" forServiceName:kStoredData updateExisting:YES error:&error];

            // apply purchase action  - hide lock overlay and
            [feature2Btn setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            // Get The Coins, rock, favor points, whatever:

            self.coins = coins +10;
            coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lld", self.coins];

        }
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:{
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view here
            statusLabel.text = @"";}
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:{

            if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view here
            statusLabel.text = @"Purchase Error!";}
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
} }
```

Not quite sure if you must add this or not:

```
-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request {
}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

This is the easiest code ever. Not sure if Apple will approve, but it is working. This works  on iOS 4.3 and higher which I think it is great, but doesn't implement the Receipts so some smart kids will be able to get coins for free.

Don't forget to create the Consumable item on iTunes Connect and change the id "com.IAPID.10coins" with the correct ID created created by you over there.

"paymentWithProductIdentifier" is deprecated but still works, to fix it change it for "paymentWithProduct" and find a way to add the IAP ID. I tried but didn't succeed.

This is ARC ready, except the "SFHFKeychainUtils.m", you can try to fix it or disable ARC on that single file, here is the tutorial: http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/8/disabling-arc-on-certain-files-in-xcode.html

You also must add the ScoreKit and Security framework to your project.

For consumable itens, thats it! For non-consumable you must add a RESTORE button or Apple will give you a rejection. But that's pretty easy:

```
// RESTORE

 - (IBAction)IAPRestore:(id)sender
 {
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
 }


 - (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
 {
     NSLog(@"Restore completed transactions finished.");
     NSLog(@" Number of transactions in queue: %d", [[queue transactions] count]);
     for (SKPaymentTransaction *trans in [queue transactions])
     {
         NSLog(@" transaction id %@ for product %@.", [trans transactionIdentifier], [[trans payment] productIdentifier]);
         NSLog(@" original transaction id: %@ for product %@.", [[trans originalTransaction] transactionIdentifier],
          [[[trans originalTransaction] payment]productIdentifier]);


    if ([[[trans payment] productIdentifier] isEqual: @"com.AppID.IAPID"]) {

        NSLog(@"Purchase Restored");

        // Do your stuff to unlock

          }

     }
     UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                         initWithTitle:@"Purchases Restored"
                         message:@"Your previously purchased products have been restored!"
                         delegate:self 
                         cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil]; 

                 [tmp show];

 }
```

I hope this is useful to someone and that Apple approves it :)

UPDATE: Apple approved it and sales are coming in just fine, iOS 4.3, 5 and 6 sales are working :)
UPDATE2: Tested and working flawlessly on Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1.2.

Comment: Is it still working fine? Looking to implement IAP into my app but wanted to check first

Answer (score 3):

If you are done with all the connection work and adding framework below code will work for sure:

## define kStoredData @"object of inapp purchase" (this is for object declaration)

```
- (void) requestProductData
{
    if(countphotoval==2)
    {
        phonetext.text=@"";
        countrycode.text=@"";
        nametext.text=@"";
        Emailtext.text=@"";
        photocounter=0;
        image1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box.png"];
        image2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box.png"];
        labelimage.text=@"Image";
        addbuttonforpicker.userInteractionEnabled=true;
        addbuttonforpicker2.userInteractionEnabled=false;
        countphotoval=0;
    }
    request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject: @"object of inapp purchase"]];
    request.delegate = self;
    
    [request start];
    
      
}
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    
    
    // populate UI
  
    }


-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        NSLog(@"transaction array-->%@",transaction.description);
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                
                // show wait view here
                //statusLabel.text = @"Processing...";
                break;
                
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startActivityindicatore) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
                [self fordataupload];
                
                break;
                
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
                
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                
                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
                    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Please provide correct Userid and Password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];
                    //                    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here
                // statusLabel.text = @"Purchase Error!";
                break;
                
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Something has went wrong" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    //If you want to save the transaction
    // [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    
    //Provide the new content
    // [self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    
    //Finish the transaction
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    
}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats!!" message:@"Your Transaction Is Completed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanx!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    //If you want to save the transaction
    // [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    
    //Provide the new content
    //[self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    
}
-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request1  
{  
    [self stopActivityindicatore];
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"VirtualBinocularsContest1"];
    NSLog(@"quality --->%d",payment.quantity);
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    [request release];
}
```

Please notify if it works for you..:)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I posted the whole code I used to create the IAP Button. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

`paymentWithProduct:` expects an `SKProduct *` argument and you are passing an `NSString`. You need to get your product out of your `_products` array and pass that instead.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It was a copy and paste problem. But it doesn't work either, this is not the real problem :)

Comment: @tomDev were you able to see if this fixed the warning?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I switched to paymentWithProductIdentifier that is easier to setup, which is deprecated but still works. I posted the whole code if anyone is interested. Thanks for the help!