# Consumable InApp purchase for a single product?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have created a sample project by following [Ray Wenderlichs](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266) and its working perfectly.But I have only one product and What I want is In a single button click it should buy that product .When i google for hours I got a solution [In-App Purchase with an IBAction / Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168407/in-app-purchase-with-an-ibaction-button) which is exactly same as my requirement. But when I used the code i am getting deprecation for "paymentWithProductIdentifier".
Is there any way to make a purchase using object of inapp purchase like "com.example.product" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass skproduct instead of its identifier, it is not very different you only got to request the product beforehand so you have it available when you are doing the payment.

```
//This is how you request the products with a list of identifiers

SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:self.productIdentifiers];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request start];

//This is the delegate method called after there is a response from apple servers

-(void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    self.products = response.products;

    for (SKProduct *product in self.products)
    {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:MY_PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER])
        {
            self.myProduct = product;
        }
    }
}

//And this is how you do the actual payment after product is retrieved

SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.myProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Transaction part works the same way as in the tutorials as far as I remember because I went through the same tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit), it will make your life easier.