# Issue with UIButton in UIViewController instead of UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am using the following code for a specific button in my UIView. Bare in mind that this code works perfectly in a UITableView but doesnt seem to work for me in a UIViewController. When I press the button it just hangs

```
 UIButton *buyButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, 370, 320, 60)];
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"upgrade-new.png"];
        [buyButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];
        [buyButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buyButton.titleLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:1.0]];
        [buyButton.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
        [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        buyButton.tag = 0;
        [[self view] addSubview:buyButton];
```

**Method for button**

```
- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = [_products objectAtIndex:buyButton.tag];

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}
```

I'd appreciate some guidance on this!

Comment: Does your target method get called at all?

Comment: yes, that's called through a shared instance

Comment: The code that is here looks fine, assuming that all of the code surrounding it is good.

Is your code making it to the buyButtonTapped function? Does products actually contain objects?

Comment: What I mean is what do you mean by "hanging". When you click it doe you see the printout of "Buying..." or does nothing happen at all

Comment: I see this printout 2014-01-08 23:47:47.805 MyApp[2236:60b] Buying (null)...

Comment: try `[buyButton setTag:0];`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when you moved this to the UIViewController you are not creating creating a proper products array. The (null) you see means that there is no product there, so of course RageIAPHelper cannot successfully purchase it

Comment: possible duplicate of [UiButton action crashing app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008271/uibutton-action-crashing-app)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some more people looking out for the same problem as you. Have a look at this post, the question was the same as yours.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14175601/1141395

For me it looks like this won't work because you have to receive available products you already added to `ITunesConnect`. You can press your `UIButton` to get the process started but the products should be received inside following `delegate` method:

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request 
    didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it worked before is most likely due to you handling your `_products` array well when you had your tableViews.

Now that you have changed this around, the chances are that something has broken with your `_products` array while you were trying to implement the button in your UIViewController

It hangs because either the application crashes or because your `RageIAPHelper` instance wasn't expecting a null object.

I suggest you follow what happens with your products array and do some debugging to find out why `null` is being returned. Just make sure your _products array is being populated correctly, ensure that the objects are inside the array maybe by printing it to double check its all there, and soon enough you'll find out exactly why your `_products` array is empty